# Why was Korach specifically punished via being swallowed by the ground?

Tags: miracle, parshat-korach

<sup>(slightly similar to:[Why did Korach have to be buried alive](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29182/why-did-korach-have-to-be-buried-alive)?)</sup>

---

In this week's Parsha, Korach and his assembly challenge Moshe's authority and are punished by being swallowed alive by the ground ([Numbers 16:31-33](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.31-33?lang=bi&aliyot=0)).

My question is: they could have all been hit by a lightning bolt, or eradicated via some other method or phenomenon.
**Why specifically was *this* the punishment that was meted out to Korach and his assembly**?

Comment: Because if it had been something else you would have asked “why not make the earth swallow him?”.

Comment: @Loani ,nice ref of the Gemara in Sanhedrin.

Comment: @Loani haha wouldn't be that specific, but you're right- I still would ask why Korach received x particular *misah*

Answer (score 4):

The [Maharal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Loew_ben_Bezalel) address this question in [Tiferes Yisrael 18](https://www.sefaria.org/Tiferet_Yisrael.18.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> **כי דבר זה היה חטא קרח ועדתו שהיו כופרים בתורה מן השמים כמו שמוכיח הכתוב, ולפיכך היה עונש קרח ועדתו שנבלעו חיים שאולה, וזה כי התורה היא תורת אמת, לא כמו שאר דברים כי עם שהם אמת, כמו אם יאמר אחד ראובן הוא בבית זה והאמת שהוא בבית, מכל מקום לא נקרא דבר זה שהוא אמת, מצד כי אפשר שלא יהיה בבית ועם שהוא אמת דבר זה הוא במקרה. וכאשר יאמר האדם ראובן איננו בבית הוא שקר אבל הוא שקר במקרה, כי היה אפשר שיהיה בבית, אבל האמת שהיא אמת בעצם היא תורת משה שהיא אמת בעצם, שכל דבריה הם מוכרחים ואי אפשר בענין אחר. וזה כי כאשר אמרה תורה אהרן הוא כהן ודבר זה אמת בעצם לפי שהוא הכרחי שכך יהיה שאי אפשר שיהיה בענין אחר**, לכך מציאות זה הוא העצם והוא הכרחי שיהיה כך ולא בענין אחר, ... וכן כל דברי תורה הם כך שמציאותם הכרחי וכמו שהתבאר בפרק שלפני זה
>   ולכך כאשר היו חולקים על התורה שכל דבריה מוכרחים במציאות, **המתנגד לזה מוכרח שאין לו מציאות כלל**, ולכך כתיב - (במדבר ט"ז) ויאבדו מתוך הקהל וירדו הם וכל אשר להם חיים שאולה שהיו מוכרחים להיות בלתי נמצאים כלל וירדו חיים שאולה שהוא האבדון. **ואלו ירדו מתים לא נקרא זה שאין ראוי להם המציאות כלל, אחר שהיו מקבלים מיתה טבעית כדרך כל הארץ** והיה להם חיים טבעיים, אבל משה אמר אם כמות כל אדם ימותון ויהיה להם המציאות אשר ראוי לנמצאים לא ה' שלחני לתת התורה כי התורה שהמציאות שלה מוכרח, **אין ראוי להתקיים החולק על המוכרח ודבר זה ברור מאד**

In summary, he says that the **Torah represents an ultimate truth**, unlike something that is technically true. If one says that "Reuven is in the house", and he is indeed in the house, although technically true, that is not considered an ultimate truth, since it is possible that Reuven would not be in the house. The Torah, however is an ultimate truth that is impossible for it to be any other way. **Since Korach denied the validity of the ultimate truth, he was no longer fitting to exist.** Therefore it is not appropriate for him to die in a normal or natural way or even to enter the grave "dead", but rather **he needed to be swallowed up by the ground alive since he obviated his own existence while alive,** by denying the ultimate truth.

The emphasis of the Maharal is on the fact they went to the grave alive. Any other punishment would have killed them, which would be inappropriate given the nature of their sin. They needed to go to the grave "alive", something not just uncommon, but fundamentally unnatural since they denied the fundamental truth.

Answer (score 3):

The Ramban writes (as well as other meforshim point this idea out, for example, Rabbeinu Bachya) that the splitting of the ground was meant to be a totally new and unique (as well as supernatural) phenomena that was unlike any other natural occurrence.

The Ramban explains how this was so different from a regular earthquake:

> ואם בריאה יברא ה' כתב ר"א יש אומרים כי בריאה תורה על המצא יש מאין וכבר
>   נבקעו מדינות רבות וירדו הדרים בהן שאולה אבל פירושה כטעם גזרה מן וברא
>   אותהן (יחזקאל כג מז) והנכון שתאמר על המצא דבר מאין כי אין אצלנו בלשון
>   הקדש מורה על זה זולתי המלה הזאת אבל הענין **כי בקיעת האדמה אינה בריאה
>   מחודשת אבל פתיחת הארץ את פיה לבלוע הוא חדוש לא נהיה מעולם כי כאשר תבקע
>   האדמה כמו שנעשה פעמים רבים ברעש הנקרא זלזלה תשאר פתוחה גם ימלא הבקע
>   מים ויעשה כאגמים אבל שתפתח ותסגר מיד כאדם הפותח פיו לבלוע ויסגור אותו
>   אחרי בלעו זה הדבר נתחדש ביום ההוא כאלו הוא נברא מאין** וזה טעם ותכס
>   עליהם הארץ (פסוק לג) ולכך אמר הכתוב אחרי ותבקע האדמה (פסוק לא) ותפתח
>   הארץ את פיה ותבלע אותם (פסוק לב) ועל דעת רבותינו (סנהדרין קי) בקרוב
>   פתח גיהנם גם הוא ענין נתחדש לשעתו

:

> If Hashem will create a [new] creation. Splitting open the ground was
>   not in fact a new creation, but that the ground would open its mouth
>   and swallow them alive was something new that had never happened. When
>   the earth splits, as has happened many times in an earthquake, it
>   remains open, and the cracks later fill with water and become like
>   lakes. **However, that the earth should open and close immediately, as a
>   man opens his mouth to swallow and closes it after he swallows — this
>   was created afresh on that day as if it were created from nothing.**
>   This is the explanation of (v. 33), “and the earth covered them,” and
>   therefore it says: “The ground beneath them split. The earth opened
>   its mouth and swallowed them.” According to the teaching of our Rabbis
>   (Sanhedrin 110a) the opening of Gehinnom drew close to them; this was
>   newly created on that day as well.

Applying this Ramban to your question, why it didn’t happen in another way, perhaps if it was lightening or any other type of events, it wouldn’t have been as discernible from other natural occurrences as much as the earth opening and closing like a mouth

Comment: Thanks! You're right re: lighting, we had already seen at Har Sinai. But then forget about lightning- why *davka* this unique natural occurrence over a different one?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three answers (based on lessons by rav Boruch Rosenblum) -
1.It was written that Moshe was the modest man on earth and we have Korach as an opposite character - so the earth made a job here.
2.If a man has some bad character traits - this somehow will reflect sooner or later on his grandsons. The only way to avoid is to take a man out of this world being a live. It means Moshe knew about Shmuel.
3.Since Korach went against Oral Torah and the Tora was given under the Har Sinai, so the punishment was that the mountain (earth) went down Korach!